# python - gearman - keep getting typeerror

Tags: python, gearman

I have a simple python script to send gearman tasks:

Client:

```
        # "source" is a simple tuple
        client = GearmanClient(['localhost'])
        client.submit_job('queue_feed', simplejson.dumps(source))
```

Server:

```
def queue_feed(work, job):
    source = simplejson.loads(job.data)
    print source

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if sys.argv[1] == "spawn":
            worker = GearmanWorker(['localhost'])
            #nohup python /home/padsquad/apps/gearman_articles.py spawn &
            worker.register_task('queue_feed', queue_feed)
            print 'working...'
            worker.work()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, the gearman server keeps giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: Expecting byte string, got <type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback so we can know what line you're getting the error on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that the function `queue_feed` is supposed to `return` something:  e.g.:

```
def queue_feed(work, job):
    source = simplejson.loads(job.data)
    print source
    return source
```

If you don't explicitly return something from a python function, it implicitly returns `None` which is why python is complaining about getting `NoneType`

Comment: That was exactly the issue, I'm still a newbie with python :)

Comment: I'll accept your answer once the accept delay is done in 5 mins

Comment: good answer - I had a similar problem with Gearman, fixed by doing a return 'somestring'